# Check type of a function parameter

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, es6-promise, ecmascript-2017

Since TypeScript is a superset of Javascript and 'Type' would be removed in the resulting js files, so I guess playing with 'type' would not work like this, right?
Also, is there any better way to do it other than having two different methods?

```
type VoidToVoidFunc = () => void;
type VoidToPromiseVoidFunc = () => Promise<void>;

async function add(func: VoidToVoidFunc  | VoidToPromiseVoidFunc) {
    if (typeof func == typeof VoidToVoidFunc)
        func(); 
    else
        await func();
}

add(() => console.log(1));
```

Comment: You are trying to do something that already exists: `const pr: Promise<void> = Promise.resolve(func());`

Comment: The simplest solution: `await func();`. In JavaScript, the `await` operator wraps any synchronous value automatically, like an implicit `Promise.resolve` call. Alternately you can check for `then`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await), when a non-thenable value follows `await`, an already-fulfilled `Promise` is constructed and used.

So the simplest implementation is to `await` the result of the function call. Indeed, `await` wraps a value in a `Promise` if it's not already a `Promise`:

```
type VoidToVoidFunc = () => void;
type VoidToPromiseVoidFunc = () => Promise<void>;

async function add(func: VoidToVoidFunc  | VoidToPromiseVoidFunc) {
  await func();
  // Do something else
}

add(() => console.log(1));
```

This behavior is correctly typed by TypeScript, indeed when you write `const test = await func();` and hover the variable, its type is correctly inferred to `void`.

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAag9gSwCYBU72QMQK4DsDGUAvFABQCUxAfFAG6JIDcAUKJLA2gAoBOcAtggDOEDEhwFiZSkRq8BwiAB56yKi2YBDISEkAzPPmAI4uKJqRJSBggC4OyNGImEoAHweo48wSOeHKAG9mKCh8UyFgKGAISKlNAHdNBCibfAoWUIB6LKgAETgoIQEIYAALBFwAcygIABsRZgBfZi1LUgpqMIi4OogAOjq4KtIARnJyRiA)

Answer (score 3):

`await` does not require its operand to be a promise! It returns the value of the awaited expression if it is not a promise.

```
await expression
```

> **expression**
> A Promise, a thenable object, or any value to wait for. 
> Reference: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

So a synchronous subroutine is allowed. With this in mind, simplify your code as follows:

```
type VoidToVoidFunc = () => void;
type VoidToPromiseVoidFunc = () => Promise;

async function add(func: VoidToVoidFunc  | VoidToPromiseVoidFunc) {
    await func(); /* <—- valid whether func() is synchronous or not. */
}

add(() => console.log(1));
```

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest and most maintainable solution is the most strait forward

```
type VoidToVoidFunc = () => void;
type VoidToPromiseVoidFunc = () => Promise<void>;

async function add(func: VoidToVoidFunc | VoidToPromiseVoidFunc) {
  await func();
}

add(() => console.log("sync function", 1));

add(async () => {
  await delay(1000);
  console.log("async function", 2);
});


function delay(ms: number) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAag9gSwCYBU72QMQK4DsDGUAvFABQCUxAfFAG6JIDcAUKJLA2gAoBOcAtggDOEDEhwFiZSkRq8BwiAB56yKi2YBDISEkAzPPmAI4uKJqRJSBggC4OyNGImEAPg9Rx5gkc8OUAb2YocwB3TQRgKBt8ChYAX2YtS1IKaih8UyE4ABsIADocuABzUgAiHX1DY1MygBooAEZycg0LK21dQjTZKCCQzXDIqCQIHM0QUkaABlnW4Iys3IKi0rLOqoIa3HqoACZ5+PmkmO2RsYnSfiF7XGx+ACMIHkCFnghgbB4zXAhQqG8ilI72yOVo0F6ImAKAQ-AgcGwwGBEFB4Ia1xaCWYQA)

```js
async function add(func) {
  await func();
}

add(() => console.log("sync function", 1));

add(async () => {
  await delay(1000);
  console.log("async function", 2);
});

function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

As you can see from the above, behavior, applying `await` to a *non Promise* value simply wraps and unwraps it. As your `add` function by virtue of being denoted `async` is necessarily going to return a `Promise` and run asynchronously (scheduled on the next tick), more complex solutions offer no benefit in your case.

Check out the [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) docs at MDN for further elaboration.

Thus, while there are indeed other ways to determine if a you received a callback that may or may not return a Promise, such as

```
type VoidToVoidFunc = () => void;
type VoidToPromiseVoidFunc = () => Promise<void>;

async function add(func: VoidToVoidFunc | VoidToPromiseVoidFunc) {
  const couldBeAPromise = func();
  if (couldBeAPromise && 'then' in couldBeAPromise) {
    await couldBeAPromise;
  }
}

add(() => console.log("sync function", 1));

add(async () => {
  await delay(1000);
  console.log("async function", 2);
});


function delay(ms: number) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAag9gSwCYBU72QMQK4DsDGUAvFABQCUxAfFAG6JIDcAUKJLA2gAoBOcAtggDOEDEhwFiZSkRq8BwiAB56yKi2YBDISEkAzPPmAI4uKJqRJSBggC4OyNGImEAPg9Rx5gkc8OUAb2YoKHxTIWBQuGwAGyQAIQgAQW9FKRt8ChYQhD0yMNiE5NSRKAAyMqgAcmAACwhcKqgEMwK4xJS+HwhA4JDzAHdNBEi2os6FEWyoAF9mOa1LUgpqKNwhOBiIADoYuABzUgAiHX1DY1MjgBooAEZycg0LK21dQhXZKCCQzSGRqCQEBimhApFuAAZIY8+mF1psdntDkdXmcCBdcNcoAAmaEzaHMZgZdEAoEg0j8IT2XDYfgAIwgPF6IR4EGA2B4ZlwEAGUBKEFILI2MVo0E+ImAKAQ-Ag0WAAogQpFNwpDxYMyAA)

```js
async function add(func) {
  const couldBeAPromise = func();
  if (couldBeAPromise && 'then' in couldBeAPromise) {
    await couldBeAPromise;
  }
}

add(() => console.log("sync function", 1));

add(async () => {
  await delay(1000);
  console.log("async function", 2);
});

function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

keeping it simple is the way to go here.

***Note:*** `void` is a TypeScript type expressing the contract of a function and guiding type inference. However, every JavaScript function and thus every TypeScript function actually returns a value. In this case `func` param of `add` returns either `undefined` or a `Promise` that resolves to `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, you cannot rely on the type since it's going to be removed once compiled to JavaScript.

However, you can check the return value of your function. With that, you can check if you should `await` the promise or simply resolve the value.

```js
type VoidToVoidFunc = () => void;
type VoidToPromiseVoidFunc = () => Promise<void>;

async function add(func: VoidToVoidFunc  | VoidToPromiseVoidFunc) {
    /* is either a pending promise or undefined */
    const value = func();

    if(value instanceof Promise) {
      await value;
    }
}
```

In the case where your function returns a promise, you are `await`-ing it. And in the case it does not, you are simply skipping the `await` part.

The following example is in plain JavaScript, to show you how it works.

```js
async function add(func) {
    /* is either a pending promise or undefined */
    const value = func();

    if(value instanceof Promise) {
      await value;
    }
}

const asyncFunction = async () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('resolving promised function');
        resolve();
    }, 1000)
  });
};

const syncFunction = () => {
    console.log('resolving normal function')
}

add(asyncFunction);

add(syncFunction);
```

Comment: -1: The `instanceof` check is unreliable and doesn't support thenables. You have an `async` functions that don't `await`. You are using the `new Promise` anti-pattern. `typeof VoidToVoidFunc` is impossible as you said, because there is no such value yet you use it.

Comment: Thank you for your feeback, I appreciate it. There's a few things wrong with my answer, moslty typos. I've done the best I can to address the issue you mentioned while keeping in mind that this is an example. I don't have a better example to simulate a pending promise than using `new Promise`. Also, it is not possible to await the `add` function in the SO snippet. Keep in mind that this code is an example and should not be taken litteraly.

Comment: While the `instanceof` keyword is not proper for "non thenables" items, there's no information on what kind of promise OP is checking for. We are all doing the best we can with the informations we have. If you feel like you can provide a better answer, please go ahead. In the end, OP will be the winner of this situation.

Comment: All you have to do is `await` the value, regardless of whether or not it's a promise. Also, promises are supposed to support thenables, according to the spec.`const res = func(); if ('then' in res && typeof res.then === 'function') return await res; else return res;`. But your code is full of other mistakes to be honest it's just not right.

Comment: Using `async` on a function that doesn't `await`. The promise Constructor is there to adapt callback-based apis. It has no application when working with promises and async functions directly. Also `await x` is effectively `await Promise.resolve(x)` so you don't even have to care.